# Java Not Writing to Console

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging

I'm working on a Java EE web application that will not output anything to the console.  It uses log4j, the log4j.properties file is set to output to stdout.  However, it is not functioning, no logging is appearing in the console.  It turns out that even System.out is not showing up in the console.  What could cause this?

I'm running MyEclipse 10.1, log4j-1.2.11, tomcat 5.5.35, java 1.6.0_31.

Per request, here is my .properties file:

```
### direct log messages to stdout ###
# Configure Root Logger
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate = DEBUG, stdout
#log4j.logger.org.springframework = ERROR, stdout

# Configure stdout Appender 
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern =%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

And log handler:

```
public class LogHandler {
private static Logger sLog = Logger.getLogger(LogHandler.class);
public LogHandler(){

}
public void info_toLOG(String msg00) {
    sLog.info("\n" + msg00 + "\n");
}

public void error_toLOG(Exception e) {
    sLog.error("\n" + e.getClass() + "\n"
            + e.getCause() + "\n"
            + e.getMessage() + "\n"
            + e.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n"
            + e.getStackTrace().toString() + "\n");
}

public void warning_toLOG(String msg00) {
    sLog.warn("\n" + msg00 + "\n");
}
```

}

I use MyEclipse to start and stop.  Just point my tomcat install dir.  MyEclipse added the following VM args:

```
-Dcatalina.home="<tomcat dir>" 
-Dcatalina.base="<tomcat dir> " 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="<tomcat dir>/common/endorsed" 
-Djava.io.tmpdir="<tomcat dir>/temp" 
-Djava.library.path=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:"<tomcat dir>/bin" 
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false 
-Xmx1024M
```

EDIT:
Thank you to those who attempted to help. I should have stated in the original question that I am running Mac OS X 10.7.3. There was a setting under Utilities -> Java Preferences -> Advanced -> Java Console that once set to Show Console corrected the issue.

Comment: log4j configuration (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) can be tricky.  In a typical setup, there are listeners set up to handle certain categories of log messages, and each listener can direct output to various destinations (my terminology, not log4j's).  If you can post your properties file, and an example line of Java code that performs a logging operation, we might be able to point out the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In Tomcat your System.out and System.err will go to catalina.out log file. Please check your output there.

**UPDATE** Having just tested your exact log4j configuration I can confirm that the output is sent to `tomcat7-stdout.<date>.log` on Tomcat 7 Windows.

```
2012-04-27 15:59:47 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
2012-04-27 15:59:51,955 [http-apr-8080-exec-3] INFO  org.apache.log4j.Logger - hey log
blah
```

This log file name would be different for Tomcat 5.5, it should be `catalina.out` in Linux, and it would have a different name in Windows (so the documentation says, I don't know).

This is the code:

```
Logger l = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class);
l.info("hey log");
System.out.println("blah");
```

**UPDATE2** Under Eclipse this type of output should go to Eclipse console, try building your WAR file and deploying it into a standalone Tomcat to verify the above.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see a catalina.out file.

Comment: What's in your `<TOMCAT_DIR>/logs` directory? I may be thinking of an earlier version of Tomcat.

Comment: In my Tomcat 7 the System.out ends up in `<TOMCAT_DIR>/logs/tomcat7-stdout.<date>.log`.

Comment: The logs dir is empty.  There isn't a .log or .out file anywhere in the tomcat directory.

Comment: In this case I'll second @DavidGorsline and will ask to look at your `log4j.properties`

Comment: Oh, it looks like with log4j this indeed goes back to console (both System.out and Logger calls). I ran your sample configuration in Eclipse and I can see both in Eclipse console. How do you run your Tomcat?

Comment: In Eclipse it will all get printed in the Eclipse console. But perhaps try checking `<YOUR_WORKPLACE_DIR>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs` as well.