# No output in console

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, console, websphere

This sounds like a trivial question but I googled about it and found nothing that helped me.

Nothing gets printed in my console. It was working just fine yesterday. I haven't made any changes to my RAD.

Even the system.out statements do not get printed in the console. I debugged to make sure it hits the system.out statement.

I have confirmed that the console I am looking at for output is the console for the websphere as shown in the picture.

I am using RAD 8 and websphere app server7.

[image]

**EDIT 1 :**

The log file(SystemOut.log)

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
WebSphere Platform 7.0.0.11 [BASE 7.0.0.11 cf111021.10] running with process name 2UA2060KBLNode01Cell\2UA2060KBLNode01\server1 and process id 2796
Host Operating System is Windows 7, version 6.1 build 7601 Service Pack 1
Java version = 1.6.0, Java Compiler = j9jit24, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7
user.install.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01
Java Home = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/java/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01/classes;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/classes;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/installedChannels;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/ext;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/web/help;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/properties;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/startup.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/jsf-nls.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/java/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre\bin;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre\bin;C:\app\RPM0C0\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\app\RPM0C0\product\11.2.0\client_2;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\idmu\common;C:\Windows\SysWow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\9.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Attachmate\Reflection\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;
************* End Display Current Environment *************
[2/20/13 14:47:47:370 CST] 0000001e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_33fd33fd_13.02.20_14.47.47.3401796267326710681783.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter 89
[2/20/13 14:47:47:470 CST] 0000001e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_33fd33fd_13.02.20_14.47.47.400854812561247672408.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch 428
[2/20/13 14:47:47:500 CST] 0000001e servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/errorhandling/error.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:30:422 CST] 0000001e servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/F_login.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:32:392 CST] 0000001c servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [FilterProxyServlet]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:32:402 CST] 0000001c servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/index.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:32:472 CST] 0000001c servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/common/topMenu.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:32:512 CST] 0000001c servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/common/sideMenu.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:32:522 CST] 0000001c DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public Map getIntlPlanningBlocks(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:32:792 CST] 0000001c HibernateAbst I com.dps.nom.dops.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractTOPSDAO createCriteria setting CacheMode.REFRESH, cacheable = false
[2/20/13 14:48:32:802 CST] 0000001c HibernateAbst I com.dps.nom.dops.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractTOPSDAO createCriteria setting CacheMode.REFRESH, cacheable = false
[2/20/13 14:48:32:932 CST] 0000001c DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public Map getIntlPlanningBlocks(...); -- 410ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:32:932 CST] 0000001c DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:32:932 CST] 0000001c DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:32:932 CST] 0000001c DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:32:942 CST] 0000001c DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:32:992 CST] 0000001c DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...); -- 50ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:32:992 CST] 0000001c DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:32:992 CST] 0000001c DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:33:002 CST] 0000001c DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:33:032 CST] 0000001c servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/common/displayErrors.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:33:052 CST] 0000001c servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/main/indexDetails.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:33:082 CST] 0000001c servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/common/bottomFooter.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:37:892 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:37:912 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...); -- 20ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:37:912 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:37:922 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:37:922 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:38:582 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public boolean isItTime2ShutDownUpdates(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:38:632 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public boolean isItTime2ShutDownUpdates(...); -- 50ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:38:632 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:38:632 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:38:632 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:38:642 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:40:762 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...); -- 2120ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:40:772 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:40:772 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:40:772 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:40:842 CST] 0000002f servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/international/routing/add_routing/route_mode_selection.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:47:333 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public Date getCurrentDateFromDBSysDate(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:47:403 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public Date getCurrentDateFromDBSysDate(...); -- 60ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:47:413 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:47:413 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:47:413 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:47:423 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:47:453 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...); -- 30ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:47:463 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:47:463 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:47:463 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:47:503 CST] 0000002f servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/international/routing/add_routing/enter_routing_info.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:47:553 CST] 0000002f servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/common/singleFacilitySelect.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:47:577 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public FacilityTO[] getFacilities(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:47:655 CST] 0000002f HibernateAbst I com.dps.nom.dops.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractTOPSDAO createCriteria setting CacheMode.REFRESH, cacheable = false
[2/20/13 14:48:47:665 CST] 0000002f HibernateAbst I com.dps.nom.dops.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractTOPSDAO createCriteria setting CacheMode.REFRESH, cacheable = false
[2/20/13 14:48:47:845 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public FacilityTO[] getFacilities(...); -- 266ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:47:845 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:47:845 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:47:845 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:47:895 CST] 0000002f servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/common/selectEntityTile.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:47:925 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public FacilityTO[] getFacilities(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:48:015 CST] 0000002f HibernateAbst I com.dps.nom.dops.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractTOPSDAO createCriteria setting CacheMode.REFRESH, cacheable = false
[2/20/13 14:48:48:015 CST] 0000002f HibernateAbst I com.dps.nom.dops.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractTOPSDAO createCriteria setting CacheMode.REFRESH, cacheable = false
[2/20/13 14:48:49:365 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public FacilityTO[] getFacilities(...); -- 1430ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:49:365 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:49:365 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:49:375 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:49:465 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public String[] getInternationalMailClasses(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:49:465 CST] 0000002f HibernateAbst I com.dps.nom.dops.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractTOPSDAO createCriteria setting CacheMode.REFRESH, cacheable = false
[2/20/13 14:48:49:465 CST] 0000002f HibernateAbst I com.dps.nom.dops.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractTOPSDAO createCriteria setting CacheMode.REFRESH, cacheable = false
[2/20/13 14:48:49:615 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public String[] getInternationalMailClasses(...); -- 150ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:49:625 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:49:625 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:49:625 CST] 0000002f DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:49:665 CST] 0000002f servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/common/mailHandlingCodesSelect.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:48:59:426 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public boolean isItTime2ShutDownUpdates(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:59:466 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public boolean isItTime2ShutDownUpdates(...); -- 40ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:59:476 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:59:476 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:59:476 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:48:59:486 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...);
[2/20/13 14:48:59:506 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...); -- 20ms.
[2/20/13 14:48:59:516 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:48:59:516 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:48:59:516 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:49:03:786 CST] 0000001b ***SystemOut     O Hi***
[2/20/13 14:49:03:786 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...);
[2/20/13 14:49:03:816 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public String getLatestIntl7DayJobId(...); -- 30ms.
[2/20/13 14:49:03:816 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:49:03:816 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:49:03:816 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:49:03:856 CST] 0000001b servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [TOPS-APP] [/TOPS-WEB-RB] [/servicecentral/international/interline/add_interline_routes.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/20/13 14:49:04:926 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public AggregateMailClassTO[] getAggregateMailClassesForDomestic(...);
[2/20/13 14:49:04:926 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Calling public AggregateMailClassTO[] getAggregateMailClassesForDomestic(...);
[2/20/13 14:49:04:936 CST] 0000001b HibernateAbst I com.dps.nom.dops.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractTOPSDAO createCriteria setting CacheMode.REFRESH, cacheable = false
[2/20/13 14:49:04:936 CST] 0000001b HibernateAbst I com.dps.nom.dops.dao.hibernate.HibernateAbstractTOPSDAO createCriteria setting CacheMode.REFRESH, cacheable = false
[2/20/13 14:49:05:056 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public AggregateMailClassTO[] getAggregateMailClassesForDomestic(...); -- 120ms.
[2/20/13 14:49:05:056 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:49:05:066 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:49:05:066 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
[2/20/13 14:49:05:066 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy invoke Exiting public AggregateMailClassTO[] getAggregateMailClassesForDomestic(...); -- 140ms.
[2/20/13 14:49:05:076 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession flushing
[2/20/13 14:49:05:076 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession clearing
[2/20/13 14:49:05:086 CST] 0000001b DebugProxy    I com.dps.nom.dops.util.DebugProxy closeSession closing
```

**EDIT 2: Solution**

I couldn't figure out what was causing this problem. So I ended up deleting the server and recreating it. This solved the issue. So I guess there was some kind of configuration change to the server that was required.

Any answer will still be appreciated.

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351753/java-not-writing-to-console/10351888#10351888

Comment: @maksimov thank you. I do see some errors logged into my log files but I would like to see it in my console as well. Console just makes things much easier.

Comment: But if you go find the SystemOut.log file that WebSphere is writing to the filesystem and that has the expected output, that will let us know whether the problem is WebSphere or RAD. Check the directory where WebSphere is intalled `...AppServer\profiles\profileName\logs\serverName`

Comment: @dbreaux I have included the log file you asked for. Thank you.

Comment: It's been awhile since I used WS last time, so can't give a lot of details, but relating to the other problem I referenced, there must be a logging configuration file in your WS where you need to specify that you want your output to be sent to stdout.

Comment: The output is in WebSphere's log, just not in RAD's console, so it's a RAD issue. (I know that doesn't resolve it for you, I'm just trying to isolate where the problem lies.)

Comment: @dbreaux @ maksimov Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in two ways:

1. Initially, I just deleted the server instance and recreated it all over again.
2. Rick clicked the RAD/Eclipse icon and selected "Run as administrator".

If you want to start your Rad or eclipse instance as an administrator by default, do the following:

```
Right click on the shortcut > Properties > Advanced > check the box "Always run as 

administrator > OK > Apply > OK
```

Answer (score 1):

The console view can display more than one kind of console. In your screenshot, it's displaying the Websphere server console. The output that you're expecting to see may be on a different console. There are some buttons to the right of the console tab which you can use to switch to a different console.

[This page](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-console_view.htm) describes the console view and the buttons which you can use to switch to a different console.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but nothing gets printed in any of the console.

Answer (score 0):

I just closed the "console" 'view' and chose Window>Show View> Console, and it fixed for me.

This answer is given based on the first image i saw here, which has the console view which is empty.