# Console does not output anything (Eclipse Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

The console has broken today for seemingly no reason. My past programs, which did output to console are now not outputting. If I even just type `System.out.println("abc");` nothing will come out. Any ideas? I tried a bunch from similar questions to no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No console output in Eclipse Juno](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504493/no-console-output-in-eclipse-juno)

Comment: just no output, or no UI at all? you'll have to be a bit more specific, than just "the console broke".

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: There is an option to set the console so that it is 'locked', i.e., doesn't take new output.  Is it possible you've clicked on that without realizing it?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are looking at wrong console. Eclipse groups different programs consoles together, and shows only one active console.

Right click on `console icon with +` symbol on top right corner of your Console window. It will list all active/in-active list of console windows.

if there is more than one console listed, then it is possible that one of that console contains your program output.

if you still can't find it, then the best bet would be to rest current `perspective`. Right click on current `Prospective` on top Right corner of your eclipse, then select `Reset` and click on `ok`.